# Retry option for Command line svn export command

Tags: jenkins, tortoisesvn

I am using svn ***Export*** command as a pre-build step (Execute windows batch command) in jenkins job.
The link I am exporting has a several external links from same SVN repo.
During execution I have observed that from command line some external links are not accessible but it accessible through internet explorer or through SVN browser. (I am using tortoise as a client)

Is there any provision in the SVN command line so that I can add retry count in case of connection failure.

Note: I am not using Jenkins subversion plugin as I want to ***export*** the SVN link and do not want ***checkout***.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the svn command line client nor the TortoiseSVN equivalent have this functionality. Instead, write your own wrapper to check the client's output for errors and retry  on failure (and have an upper bound on the number of retries so you don't get stuck in a loop forever).

If you're automating with no user interaction, you should be using `svn.exe`, not `tortoiseproc.exe`. Or better yet, a client library for the scripting/programming environment of your choice (SharpSVN, SVNKit SVN::Client, pysvn, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I want to implement this as pre-build action in my Jenkins job configuration. I have writeen my own wrapper for this.

Thank you.